# Calculate new values based on multiple conditions from other columns

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements

A filtered data set is provided here:

```
     ID       Date Location   Method Lines Session_Number Start_Session End_Session
1  1257 2017-02-02     FSZ5 Trolling     2              1         07:11        <NA>
2  1258 2017-02-02     FSZ5 Trolling     2              1         07:11        <NA>
3  1259 2017-02-02     FSZ5 Trolling     2              1         07:11       07:49
4  1260 2017-02-02     FSZ6   Bottom     5              2         08:05       07:49
5  1261 2017-02-02     FSZ6   Bottom     5              2         08:05       07:49
6  1262 2017-02-02     FSZ6   Bottom     5              2         08:05       07:49
7  1263 2017-02-02     FSZ6   Bottom     5              2         08:05       07:49
93 1349 2017-03-26     FSZ1   Bottom     3              3         18:28       18:23
94 1350 2017-03-26     FSZ1   Bottom     3              3         18:28       18:23
95 1351 2017-03-26     FSZ1   Bottom     3              3         18:28       18:45
   Session_Length                  Species
1              NA         Aprion virescens
2              NA        Euthynnus affinis
3              NA                     <NA>
4              NA Epinephelus multinotatus
5              NA        Caranx melampygus
6              NA        Caranx melampygus
7              NA           Lutjanus bohar
93             NA Epinephelus multinotatus
94             NA      Lethrinus olivaceus
95             NA                     <NA>

stack.example <- structure(list(ID = c(1257L, 1258L, 1259L, 1260L, 1261L, 1262L,1263L, 1349L, 1350L, 1351L), Date = structure(c(17199, 17199,17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17251, 17251, 17251), class = "Date"),Location = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L,1L), .Label = c("FSZ1", "FSZ2", "FSZ3", "FSZ4", "FSZ5", "FSZ6","Other location"), class = "factor"), Method = structure(c(2L,2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bottom","Trolling"), class = "factor"), Lines = c("2", "2", "2","5", "5", "5", "5", "3", "3", "3"), Session_Number = c("1","1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3"), Start_Session = c("07:11","07:11", "07:11", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "18:28","18:28", "18:28"), End_Session = c(NA, NA, "07:49", "07:49","07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "18:23", "18:23", "18:45"), Session_Length = c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Species = structure(c(3L,13L, NA, 10L, 5L, 5L, 24L, 10L, 19L, NA), .Label = c("Acanthocybium solandri","Aethaloperca rogaa", "Aprion virescens", "Caranx ignobilis","Caranx melampygus", "Cephalopholis sonnerati", "Elagatis bipinnulata","Epinephelus fasciatus", "Epinephelus fuscoguttatus", "Epinephelus multinotatus","Epinephelus polyphekadion", "Epinephelus tukula", "Euthynnus affinis","Gymnosarda unicolor", "Lethrinus conchyliatus", "Lethrinus lentjan","Lethrinus microdon", "Lethrinus nebulosus", "Lethrinus olivaceus","Lethrinus rubrioperculatus", "Lethrinus variegatus", "Lutjanidae spp.","Lutjanus bengalensis", "Lutjanus bohar", "Lutjanus rivulatus","Momotaxis gradoculis", "Other species", "Plectropomus pessuliferus","Sphyraena barracuda", "Thunnus albacares", "Variola louti"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Location","Method", "Lines", "Session_Number", "Start_Session", "End_Session","Session_Length", "Species"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L,6L, 7L, 93L, 94L, 95L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to achieve a column i.e. `Session_Length` where minutes are calculated 
using the columns `Session_Start` and `Session_End`.

The length in minutes should correspond to a specific Date, Location, Method, and `Session_Number`. Sestraightforwardward.

Where I am struggling is that my dataset has an incorrect start and end session times for each fish caught, **with the exception** of a summarised row produced at the bottom of each fishing session that provides correct start and end times of a fishing session (raw data exported from CyberTracker).

**So, I am trying to**:

- Take the bottom row value for a corresponding session with the correct start and end time
- Work out the length of time (in minutes)
- Apply the value to the Session_Length column for each row within a specific  fishing session relating to Date, Location, Method and Session_Number

**Example**

On **`2017-02-02`** `2` fish were caught **`Trolling`**

A row is produced that gives the start **07:11** and end **`07:49`** time for `Session_Number` **`1`**

Therefore Session_Length for Session_Number **`1`** would have row values of **`48`** for the 2 fish caught during the fishing session.

I could go about it manually but I would take some time with `1000`'s of observations. Can anyone provide a means of doing this?
I'm thinking about **`dplyr`** -  `group_by` function but having trouble piecing it all together.

To remove the summarised row after calculating and applying the `Session_Length` value would be a cherry on the top.

`Session_Start` and `Session_End` columns are character classes with `NA` values present.

**EDIT NEW SAMPLE DATA**

```
stack.example2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(1257:1351, class = "integer"),Date = structure(c(17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199,17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199,17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17199, 17226, 17226,17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226,17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226,17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17226, 17232,17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232, 17232,17232, 17232, 17250, 17250, 17250, 17250, 17250, 17250, 17250,17250, 17250, 17250, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251,17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251,17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251, 17251), class = "Date"),Location = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L,3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L,5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FSZ1","FSZ2", "FSZ3", "FSZ4", "FSZ5", "FSZ6", "Other location"), class = "factor"),Method = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Bottom","Trolling"), class = "factor"),
                 Lines = structure(c("2","2", "2", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5","5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "2", "2", "2", "3","3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3","3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "2","2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "4", "4", "4","4", "4", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "2", "2", "3","3", "3", "3", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3","3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), class = "integer"),Session_Number = structure(c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2","2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2","2", "2", "2", "3", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4","4", "4", "5", "5", "5", "6", "6", "6", "6", "6", "7", "8","8", "8", "8", "8", "9", "9", "10", "10", "1", "1", "1","1", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "5", "1", "2", "2","2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2","2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3","3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), class = "integer"),
                 Start_Session = structure(c("07:11","07:11", "07:11", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05","08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05","08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "08:05", "10:31","07:19", "07:19", "07:29", "07:29", "07:29", "07:57", "08:08","08:08", "08:08", "08:08", "08:23", "08:23", "08:23", "08:36","08:36", "08:36", "08:36", "08:36", "08:52", "09:06", "09:06","09:06", "09:06", "09:06", "09:27", "09:27", "09:46", "09:46","10:47", "10:47", "10:47", "10:47", "11:03", "11:03", "11:51","11:51", "12:31", "12:31", "12:31", "12:48", "16:54", "17:08","17:08", "17:08", "17:08", "17:08", "17:08", "17:51", "17:51","18:13", "18:18", "18:18", "18:18", "18:18", "18:28", "18:28","18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28","18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28", "18:28","18:28", "18:28", "18:28"), class = "character"),
                 End_Session = structure(c(NA,NA, "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49","07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49","07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "07:49", "10:30", "10:41",NA, "07:28", "07:28", "07:28", "07:47", "08:08", "08:08","08:08", "08:08", "08:17", "08:17", "08:17", "08:34", "08:34","08:34", "08:34", "08:34", "08:51", "09:03", "09:03", "09:03","09:03", "09:03", "09:26", "09:26", "09:38", "09:38", "10:34","10:34", "10:34", "10:34", "11:03", "11:03", "11:51", "11:51","12:09", "12:09", "12:09", "12:47", "13:03", "17:03", "17:03","17:03", "17:03", "17:03", "17:03", "17:44", "17:44", "18:12","18:27", "18:27", "18:27", "18:27", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23","18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23","18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23", "18:23","18:23", "18:23", "18:45"), class = "character"), Session_Length = structure(c(NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "character"),
                 Species = structure(c(3L,13L, NA, 10L, 5L, 5L, 24L, 8L, 11L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 25L, 9L,24L, 10L, 2L, 11L, 31L, 12L, NA, NA, 19L, NA, 18L, 18L, NA,NA, 18L, 10L, 18L, NA, 6L, 19L, NA, 3L, 6L, 3L, 18L, NA,NA, 6L, 18L, 18L, 18L, NA, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 4L, 4L, 29L, NA,1L, NA, 4L, NA, 10L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, 10L, 24L, 12L, 12L,24L, NA, 4L, NA, NA, 24L, 24L, 31L, NA, 14L, 1L, 1L, 1L,30L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 10L, 10L,10L, 19L, NA), .Label = c("Acanthocybium solandri", "Aethaloperca rogaa","Aprion virescens", "Caranx ignobilis", "Caranx melampygus","Cephalopholis sonnerati", "Elagatis bipinnulata", "Epinephelus fasciatus","Epinephelus fuscoguttatus", "Epinephelus multinotatus","Epinephelus polyphekadion", "Epinephelus tukula", "Euthynnus affinis","Gymnosarda unicolor", "Lethrinus conchyliatus", "Lethrinus lentjan","Lethrinus microdon", "Lethrinus nebulosus", "Lethrinus olivaceus","Lethrinus rubrioperculatus", "Lethrinus variegatus", "Lutjanidae spp.","Lutjanus bengalensis", "Lutjanus bohar", "Lutjanus rivulatus","Momotaxis gradoculis", "Other species", "Plectropomus pessuliferus","Sphyraena barracuda", "Thunnus albacares", "Variola louti"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Location","Method", "Lines", "Session_Number", "Start_Session", "End_Session","Session_Length", "Species"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-95L))
```

Comment: it seems you have filtered rows `1:7` and `93:95` resulting in column `End_Session` not making sense anymore. Can you filter something else? Say `1:11` ending with a new `End_Session` value?

Comment: I agree with @Shique, for second group negative times are calculated based on this data. If I understand correctly, for each group, start and end times should be replaced by start and end times in the last row of that group?

Comment: @Shique I filtered my data frame beforehand using `dplyr` and then for this example I used `devtools` `reproduce` to provide an example data set. Now I understand that it selects 70% from the top rows and 30% from the bottom. I'll try to produce workable data. Sorry

Comment: No need to apologize! We are here to learn :). Have you tried @missuse 's answer already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

stack.example %>%
  mutate(End_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, End_Session, sep ="/")),
         Start_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, Start_Session, sep ="/"))) %>%
  group_by(Location, Date, Method,  Session_Number) %>%
  mutate(End_Session = tail(End_Session, 1),
         Start_Session = tail(Start_Session, 1)) %>%
  mutate(Session_Length = End_Session - Start_Session) %>%
  filter(row_number()!=n())
#output
# A tibble: 7 x 10
# Groups: Location, Date, Method, Session_Number [3]
     ID Date       Location Method   Lines Session_Number Start_Session       End_Session         Session_Length Species                 
  <int> <date>     <fct>    <fct>    <chr> <chr>          <dttm>              <dttm>              <time>         <fct>                   
1  1257 2017-02-02 FSZ5     Trolling 2     1              2017-02-02 07:11:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 38             Aprion virescens        
2  1258 2017-02-02 FSZ5     Trolling 2     1              2017-02-02 07:11:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 38             Euthynnus affinis       
3  1260 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 -16            Epinephelus multinotatus
4  1261 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 -16            Caranx melampygus       
5  1262 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 -16            Caranx melampygus       
6  1349 2017-03-26 FSZ1     Bottom   3     3              2017-03-26 18:28:00 2017-03-26 18:45:00 17             Epinephelus multinotatus
7  1350 2017-03-26 FSZ1     Bottom   3     3              2017-03-26 18:28:00 2017-03-26 18:45:00 17             Lethrinus olivaceus
```

First convert the time to `POSIXct`, then make the groups. Within each group replace `Start` and `End` values with the last value for that group. Calculate the `length` and remove the last row for each group. 
The result don't have much sense, but I trust this is due to unfortunate row sample provided in the question.

UPDATE: with the new data. I added an additional line to convert the  `Session_Length` from seconds to H:M:S using `seconds.to.hms` from `kimisc`. The warning massages are just to inform you there were NA values.

```
library(kimisc)
stack.example2 %>%
  mutate(End_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, End_Session, sep ="/")),
         Start_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, Start_Session, sep ="/"))) %>%
  group_by(Location, Date, Method,  Session_Number) %>%
  mutate(End_Session = tail(End_Session, 1),
         Start_Session = tail(Start_Session, 1)) %>%
  mutate(Session_Length = End_Session - Start_Session,
         Session_Length = seconds.to.hms(Session_Length)) %>%
  filter(row_number()!=n()) 
#output
# A tibble: 70 x 10
# Groups: Location, Date, Method, Session_Number [19]
      ID Date       Location Method   Lines Session_Number Start_Session       End_Session         Session_Length Species 
   <int> <date>     <fct>    <fct>    <chr> <chr>          <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>          <fct>   
 1  1257 2017-02-02 FSZ5     Trolling 2     1              2017-02-02 07:11:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 00:38:00       Aprion ~
 2  1258 2017-02-02 FSZ5     Trolling 2     1              2017-02-02 07:11:00 2017-02-02 07:49:00 00:38:00       Euthynn~
 3  1260 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Epineph~
 4  1261 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Caranx ~
 5  1262 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Caranx ~
 6  1263 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Lutjanu~
 7  1264 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Epineph~
 8  1265 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Epineph~
 9  1266 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Aprion ~
10  1267 2017-02-02 FSZ6     Bottom   5     2              2017-02-02 08:05:00 2017-02-02 10:30:00 02:25:00       Epineph~
```

If you would like to avoid the warnings you can do:

```
stack.example2 %>%
  group_by(Location, Date, Method,  Session_Number) %>%
  mutate(End_Session = tail(End_Session, 1),
         Start_Session = tail(Start_Session, 1),
         End_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, End_Session, sep ="/")),
         Start_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, Start_Session, sep ="/")),
         Session_Length = End_Session - Start_Session,
         Session_Length = seconds.to.hms(Session_Length)) %>%
  filter(row_number()!=n())
```

EDIT:

```
stack.example2 %>%
  group_by(Location, Date, Method,  Session_Number) %>%
  mutate(End_Session = tail(End_Session, 1),
         Start_Session = tail(Start_Session, 1),
         End_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, End_Session, sep ="/")),
         Start_Session = ymd_hm(paste(Date, Start_Session, sep ="/")),
         Session_Length = End_Session - Start_Session,
         Session_Length = seconds.to.hms(Session_Length),
         n = n()) %>%
  filter(n == 1 | row_number() != n ) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: Hi @missuse I receive a `Warning message: 3 failed to parse` which I think is because of NA's in my `End_Session` column. I've edited my question and provided an addition sample of my data. B

Comment: The warning is irrelevant, it is there to inform you you have NA values in the data  - we handle them afterward.

Comment: Added a solution that does not produce warnings.

Comment: Thank you very much @missuse most definitely the cherry on the the top. I have noticed that for sessions where no fish are caught i.e.  `ID` `1319` are also removed. Is there a way to leave these values in the data frame and calculate the time difference?

Comment: Glad to be of help. Check update please to see if it solves the problem.

Comment: that solves the problem. I don't quite understand the code itself `filter(n == 1 | row_number() != n ) %>% select(-n)` but I will try to work it out

Comment: first we create a variable `n` using the function `n()`, then we filter the data frame if `n` is 1 or if  `row_number() != n`.